# Geo Chart for Canada is not working in GoodData. Any alternative solution for this?

Tags: bigdata, gooddata, cloud-connect

I am trying to add a widget Geo Chart in GoodData.
When I populate data for Canada in Geo Chart its not giving any result,
same thing when I tried for US it was giving result.
Can any one help to resolve this issue or an alternative solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is documentation that should help you with setting up GoeCharts:

https://help.gooddata.com/display/doc/Setting+up+Data+for+Geo+Charts
https://help.gooddata.com/display/doc/Tutorial+-+Build+a+Geo+Chart

In regards to Canada - As you will see, it is not listed in the above documentation. At this point in time, we only have polygons for "Highest Population Centers" for Canada.

If polygons from "Highest Population Centers" is not sufficient you would have to provide your own polygons from a free source.

To set the geolabel to Canada "Highest Population Centers":

Identify Attribute where your geodata is stored
Go to grey pages of this attribute: /gdc/md//obj/
Identify label that has your data (there is an array called "displayForms" in the definition, there is one or more labels). Get the uri value from there (it will be in form of "/gdc/md//obj/"
Modify the Label definition (use appropriate label type from the table above instead of "GDC.geo.capopcenters.pcpuid")
Go to /gdc/md//obj/?mode=edit and add following to the content part and submit. type: GDC.geo.capopcenters.pcpuid

Comment: Thanks for the response. So you are telling I can create my own geo label..can you please share some sample screen shots so that it will helpful for me

Comment: By this method will I get a solution.

Comment: Sure: https://help.gooddata.com/display/doc/Setting+up+Data+for+Geo+Charts - this should cover the basics.